# How can I record audio to WAV file?

Tags: audio, processing

I have created a program that generated sounds in Processing. I want to export the sounds that I have created to a WAV file. I have searched online for tutorials but I only managed to find those that record sounds through the microphone. Is there a way to save sounds on Processing without going through the recording from the microphone?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the minim Audio Library [minim](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/) which offers an AudioRecorder object. Maybe you have to write a class that implements the Recordable interface first.